# How does the jasper report xsi:schemaLocation attribute take the version of jasper reports into account

Tags: jasper-reports

I upgraded jasper reports from 6.12 to 6.20.  I am getting strange errors where xml tags that seem like they should be valid are causing exceptions.  I looked at the `schemalocation` attribute and to my surprise it doesn't seem to have changed even though the schema *has* changed.

Is it that the jasper xsd schemas are back compatible?

Here's an example. Note the path containing `xsd`. That's where I expected a version number.

```
<jasperReport xmlns = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports
   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
   name = "jasper_report_template" (snip)>
```

Maybe this example (from tutorials point) is obsolete?

Comment: `Is it that the jasper xsd schemas are back compatible?` - No, in common case